# Enzyme/Jest Testing Error - Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme, jestjs

I'm new to doing unit testing and I keep getting the error: Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element. I think it has to do with the way my app.js is structured because it keeps referencing this line ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('app'));.  Here's how it's structured now:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HomePage from './HomePage';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <HomePage />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Does this need to be restructured for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You should separate between the two parts of the file, the Component declaration & mounting into the Dom via `ReactDom`.

The `ReactDom` has nothing todo with tests.

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HomePage from './HomePage';

```
// App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './HomePage';

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <HomePage />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// index.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {App} from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: My webpage is no longer rendering. How would I go about importing the index.js file into my HomePage component so that everything renders? Right now the HomePage component is importing App from ./app.js

Comment: You probably should change the entry point of you app in you webpack.config